# Logfile lost when using Log4J/GWT under Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gwt, log4j

I have create a fresh new GWT 2.6.0 project with

```
webappcreator -out TestLog4J com.example.testlog4j
```

I import it into Eclipse using "Import existing project.."

I copy log4j-api-2.0.1.jar and log4j-core-2.0.1.jar to TestLog4J/war/WEB-INF/lib (directory has to be created first) and add them to the build path.

I then create log4j2.xml in WEB-INF/lib  (right place?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="30">

<Appenders>
    <File name="Test" fileName="test.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Test" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

In GreetingServiceImpl, I add:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

and in the class

```
Logger  logger  = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
```

and in the method greetServer

```
logger.info("xxxxxxx TEST MESSAGE xxxxxxxx);");
```

I build in the TestLog4J dir using

```
ant war
```

and I load and deploy the WAR file into Tomcat using webpage at localhost:8080

Now I run the app, but where is the test.log file ???  I can't find it anywhere?

Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Comment: check in the path  where your log4j2.xml is

Comment: i mean check for the log file in that path or the root of your web app

Comment: It's in /Library/Tomcat/webapps/testlog4j/WEB-INF/lib/log4j2.xml. My guess is that it is in the wrong place but I'm not sure where to put it?

Comment: so you found your log file then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61200/discussion-between-abhin-and-peter-andersson).

Comment: <Root level="trace"> change level to "ALL" and check first if you get the logs.

If not you have to verify log4j being picked up by tomcat classpath scan..you can first check if log4j is actually picked up by printing to the console instead of log and see if you get logs in the console.